# Deploying Standard Value Set

Tags: picklist, change-set

I am trying to deploy a standard picklist, aka Standard Value Set, via Changeset. I know that via ANT I can use the `StandardValueSet` element to do it.

What is the changeset equivalent for that? Or, else, how can I deploy `Case.Origin`?

Comment: Note: I found https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162503/how-to-deploy-standard-field-permissions, but I am not sure if this is exactly the same answer (especially since that answer is a year old)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like this is currently impossible, according to the following [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG) :(

**Latest Comment from Salesforce**

> We are currently considering making Standard Value Sets available in
>   change sets, which supposevely will solve some of the issues listed in
>   this idea. Thanks everyone for commenting and contributing to this
>   idea!